# Is there a way to bypass mass assignment protection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I have a Rails 3 app which JSON encodes objects in order to store them in a Redis key/value store.

When I retrieve the objects, I'm trying to decode the JSON and instantiate them from the data like so:

```
def decode(json)
  self.new(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)["#{self.name.downcase}"])
end
```

The problem is that doing this involves mass assignment which is disallowed (for good reason I'm told!) for attributes I haven't given attr_writer ability to.

Is there a way I can bypass the mass assignment protection just for this operation only?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`assign_attributes` with `without_protection: true` seems less intrusive:

```
user = User.new
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true }, :without_protection => true)
user.name       # => "Josh"
user.is_admin?  # => true
```

@tovodeverett mentioned in the comment you can also use it with `new`, like this in 1 line

```
user = User.new({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true }, :without_protection => true)
```

Comment: This should be the answer, IMO!

Comment: Also, it appears that one can pass `without_protection: true` in the initial call to `new` (i.e. `user = User.new({name: 'Josh', is_admin: true}, without_protection: true)`

Comment: Also works when passed directly into the `create` action:
`User.create({name: 'Josh', is_admin: true}, without_protection: true)`

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** [kizzx2's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047833/76456) Answer is a much better solution.

Kind of a hack, but...

```
self.new do |n|
  n.send "attributes=", JSON.decode( json )["#{self.name.downcase}"], false
end
```

This invokes attributes= passing false for the guard_protected_attributes parameter which will skip any mass assignment checks.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had to fix two small typos though, the dot after "self" and the open curly brace for self.name.downcase.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a user also in this way which is not doing the mass assignment.

```
User.create do |user|
  user.name = "Josh"
end
```

You may want to put this into a method.

```
new_user(name)
  User.create do |user|
    user.name = name
  end
end
```