# How to set two foreign keys with a Rake Task in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake-task

I have a rake task to create a number of `invoices` in my Rails application:

```
def make_invoices
  Project.all.each do |project|
    i = project.invoices.create!( :number     => random_number,
                                  :date       => random_date,
                                  :recipient  => random_recipient,
                                  :user_id    => project.person.user.id)        
    i.created_at = random_time
    i.save
  end
end
```

This line causes the rake task to fail, however:

```
:user_id => project.person.user.id
```

And I get the following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id
```

I know why this happens.

But I need to run this rake task and I wonder if there's any way to *force mass-assign* or something?

Each invoice's `project_id` is set automatically by the `invoices.create!` method. But what if I need to set a `user_id` as well?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it outside of the call to `create` and change it to `build`:

```
def make_invoices
  Project.all.each do |project|
    i = project.invoices.build( :number     => random_number,
                                  :date       => random_date,
                                  :recipient  => random_recipient)   

    i.user_id = project.person.user.id
    i.save!

    i.created_at = random_time
    i.save
  end
end
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Why is `build` better than `create` in this context? Do I really need to call `save` twice here?

Comment: Create will initialize and save the model to the database, where build just initializes it. No, you don't need save twice, I just put it there to keep the same behavior as your original code, but you can get rid of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

[(Possible duplicate of *"Is there a way to bypass mass assignment protection?"*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659850/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-mass-assignment-protection)

It seems that [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) can do that:

```
user = User.new
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true }, :without_protection => true)
user.name       # => "Josh"
user.is_admin?  # => true
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I saw your answer too late but I will use it next time for sure!