# Rails update_attributes without forbidden attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible in a controller to use update_attributes or a similar mass update method but without having to permit the params in the controller ? I want to skip the forbidden attributes thing (my scenario is that I have admin controllers , so once I'm authenticated I just want to update things).
e.g something like this

```
@story.update_attributes(params[:story],skip)
```

I only saw ways to skip model validations in save ,
 e.g

```
@story.save(false)
```

but can't see anything for params in the controller , no way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing option:

> :without_protection => true

what you need to do is:

```
@story.update_attributes(params[:story], :without_protection => true)
```

Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659850/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-mass-assignment-protection).